# PHP redirect to different URL depending on what URL is entered in browsers

Tags: php, url, redirect, browser

I have 2 domains in the same hosting account that share the same IP address. I want to redirect to different URLS depending on which domain a user types in their browser. I want to use PHP.

EXAMPLE:

```
<?php
If browser URL is www.example.com or example.com
REDIRECT to www.example.com

ELSE if;

browser URL is www.example.org or example.org
REDIRECT to www.example.org
?>
```

Thanks I am a novice so please detail and it should work on all browsers.

Comment: Why not use .htaccess? Much simpler.

Comment: `www.example.com` redirects to `www.example.com`? Hello infinite loop...

Comment: doesnt all urls do that `google.com` directs u to `www.google.com` ?

Comment: Definitely a job for .htaccess. You want a 301 redirect.

Comment: "Thanks I am a novice so please detail and it should work on all browsers." -- this sounds like you're hiring us to do this for you. Please ask a clear question, and in the process, show us what you've tried. :)

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not clear what exactly you want. If you have two domains pointing  (DNS) to the same IP address then when you insert each of these addresses in browser you'll go to that IP address (to that machine/server). That server can (if it is configured) distinguish these requests according to address name and redirect these requests for example to different subfolders - this is called **virtual hosting**. Try search term 'virtual hosting' and find out what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you *have* to do this in PHP? It can be done in but it requires rebuilding the URL; something like

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/^www\./', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == 0) {
  $url = "http://www." . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
  header( "Location: $url" ); 
  exit();
}    
?>
```

(For why you should use 301, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298/how-to-redirect-sitea-to-siteb-with-a-or-cname-records))

Note that this doesn't handle HTTPS or requests on ports other than port 80. If you are using Apache, you can do it using the mod_rewrite engine; the `.htaccess` file supplied with the [HTML 5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) contains an example.

Comment: I just want my site to work in all browsers with the redirect which is why I said that since i have 2 domains in one host. 

I added an ELSE statement for another site, but I am not a developer. I just can modify existing PHP here and there. 

I don't know how to use htaccess to do this and since my host has PHP, i wanted to use PHP. 

Are you guys saying it is not easy in php? How to do it in htaccess? 

In KENS php example, where do I put the URLs as in my initial example... lol 

Sorry..

Comment: Doing this in .htaccess *will* work in all browsers.

There is no need to hard-code the URLs; the PHP code I supplied checks if the host name begins with "WWW." and adds it if it doesn't.

It is better to do this with the .htaccess file because otherwise you would have to add this PHP code to every script in your application (or use the auto_prepend_file directive in php.ini) If you download the HTML 5 Boilerplate .zip file from the link I gave, you will find a sample .htaccess file with instructions on how to do this. The file is well-commented.

Comment: i am looking at the boiler htaccess.. what heading should i look under?

Comment: See the section following the comment "Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs"