# Serve my app engine service from a clients sub-domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

How can I set up,

Xxx.customer.com/path

To actually field content from

Myapp.com/path

Without using a proxy on customer's server?

Is it possible using DNS records?

Myapp is a Google app engine app serving.

Comment: Do all of your clients use Google Apps?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible then.

Comment: If the req was to use G Apps the client could " add to domain"?

Comment: I think that is the only way for them to use an app engine app with their domain name / custom url.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with CNAME. As per here : [How to redirect siteA to siteB with A or CNAME records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298/how-to-redirect-sitea-to-siteb-with-a-or-cname-records)

This makes it possible to redirect one subdomain to another name.

I can detect the request address and serve the customers resource appropriately.

Customer only needs add a CNAME.

Comment: However, perhaps this will not work as the record will resolve to Google app engine ip address and will not be recognized. Unsure, clarification from GAE would work!